# Reduce the distance between plot title and map

Tags: r, plot, raster, shapefile

```
library(raster)
france <- getData('GADM', country = 'FRA', level = 1)

plot(france, main = "my.title")
```

[image]

```
par(mfrow = c(1,2))
plot(france, main = "my.title")
plot(france, main = "my.title")
```

[image]

How can I reduce the distance between my.title and map? I tried this but it only increases the size of the map

```
par(mar = c(0, 0, 0, 0))
par(mfrow = c(1,2))
plot(france, main = "my.title")
plot(france, main = "my.title")
```

Comment: Try with `?title` i.e. `plot(france);
 title("my.title", line = -1)`  Similarly for the second case `par(mfrow = c(1,2))
> plot(france)
> title("my.title1", line = -0.8)
> plot(france)
> title("my.title2", line = -0.8)`

Comment: Actually,  you can add the `line` argument directly in the plot statement.